# pcntl_fork zombies on homestead php 7 / nginx

Tags: php, nginx, pcntl

I've troubleshooted this every which way and yet can't find out why this problem is happening. I am using pcntl_fork, and pcntl_wait like this:

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();
if ($pid == -1) {
     die('could not fork');
} else if ($pid) {
     // we are the parent
     pcntl_wait($status); //Protect against Zombie children
} else {
     // we are the child
}
```

I am able to fork properly. When I look at my processes, the child process remains even after the script has completed. Every time I run this, another fork is created, and is not killed. I have tried posix_kill (returns success code), I have tried pcntl_waitpid(), and no matter what, the process remains running. They do NOT become defunct either. Thanks guys.

Comment: `pcntl_wait` shouldn't return until the child exits. It returns the PID of the child that exited. What is it returning, and is it the same as `$pid`?

Comment: A process becomes defunct when it exits before its parent has called wait. If the parent exits before the child, the child becomes an orphan, and its parent changes to `init`.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I stumbled upon the answer. I had thought the issue might be with pcntl_wait because it didn't return a response. I added:

Comment: You added what? It shouldn't return at all until the child has exited.

Comment: posix_kill(getmypid(), SIGKILL);

to the end of every child process. Thus slaying the erstwhile zombie. pcntl_wait then returns and everything works!

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary. `pctl_wait()` will return when the child terminates for any reason, it doesn't have to be from a signal.